# Unable to get Youtube Channel Name in node.js using Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

I am not interested in using any API nor am I interested in any other library other than request-promie and cheerio. I am trying to get the name of a yt channel when I enter a link to the yt channel page. The text is inside a unique tag and is formatted like this: `<yt-formatted-string id="text" class="style-scope ytd-channel-name">NAME OF CHANNEL</yt-formatted-string>` I have tried the following

```
$('yt-formatted-string', html).text()
$('.ytd-channel-name', html).text()
$('div > yt-formatted-string', html).text()
```

and some other combinations but it seems as if the cheerio library is unable to recognize custom crafted tags such as "yt-formatted-string" as well as their attributes! Any suggestions on how to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below fragment? It works for me,

```
const $ = cheerio.load(`<yt-formatted-string id="text" class="style-scope ytd-channel-name">NAME OF CHANNEL</yt-formatted-string>`);

const a = $('yt-formatted-string').text(); //NAME OF CHANNEL
```

Comment: That returns a blank a blank for me. I am using the latest version of cheerio and node.js

Comment: can you please may be attach your sample code here? The fragment which extracts the channel name.

Comment: Check it here -> https://repl.it/repls/GracefulExtraneousImplementation

Comment: that may work for you when only that tag is loaded but I want to grab from the youtube website. Please do not get stuck on simplifications, they can be guides but not in this problem.